# ROS1 ROS2 porting help?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have a **std::queue** defined like this

```
std::queue<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr> pointCloudBuf;
```

I wanted to understand how to define this in ROS2 , i tried the following but

```
std::queue<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::ConstPtr> pointCloudBuf;
```

When trying to push to the queue

```
void velodyneHandler(const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr laserCloudMsg)
{
    mutex_lock.lock();
    pointCloudBuf.push(*laserCloudMsg);
    mutex_lock.unlock();
   
}
```

i am getting the following error

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::queue<std::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > > >::push(std::__shared_ptr_access<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic, false, false>::element_type&)’
   61 |     pointCloudBuf.push(*laserCloudMsg);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

UPDATE

```
std::queue<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr> pointCloudBuf;
```

This seem to have solved my compilation issues , dont know if it will break something else down the line .

Anyhow , thankyou ROS community !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417122/ros1-ros2-porting-help-?/) by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2023-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try changing your declaration to the following. You've declared for `ConstPtr` but using for `SharedPtr`.

`std::queue<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr> pointCloudBuf;`

---

Originally posted by [Gaurav Gupta](https://answers.ros.org/users/72874/gaurav-gupta/) with karma: 276 on 2023-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2023-07-03**:
@chrissunny94: the problem is that your code has incompatible types for the queue and the callback argument.

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2023-07-04**:
@Gaurav Gupta  (small world!), thanks a lot .  saw your answer just now . .

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2023-07-04**:
@Mike Scheutzow , yup looks like my code has a lot of incompatible types , sorting it now . Will post my finding soond .

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2023-07-05**:
@Gaurav Gupta ,yup making it into shared_ptr , seems to have solved the problem . Someone in office also suggested the same solution .

**Comment by [Gaurav Gupta](https://answers.ros.org/users/72874/gaurav-gupta/) on 2023-07-05**:
Yup! Glad it is all sorted now :)